# What software/hardware do I need for switching keyboard, mouse and monitors between two computers?

Tags: networking, kvm-switch

Here is my situation:

1. I have two computers and two large monitors
2. USB keyboard and mouse
3. I need to be able to switch both monitors, keyboard and mouse from
   one computer to the other.
4. I purchased a KVM switch, but it only does VGA and only switches one of the monitors. Also, it frequently doesn't work as Windows 7 - "USB device not recognized"

Is there a software solution for accomplishing this?

Comment: Note that pure shopping recommendations (i.e. "which inexpensive hardware") are off topic. It would be better to gather answers that are still valid in a couple of months from now.

Comment: I googled for "dual-monitor KVM" and got plenty of hits.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I think I'm against the switches; having had a bad experience and wasted money already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard some people having luck with [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/).

> Synergy is Free and Open Source Software that lets you easily **share your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers, where each computer has its own display**. No special hardware is required, all you need is a local area network. Synergy is supported on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. Redirecting the mouse and keyboard is as simple as moving the mouse off the edge of your screen. Synergy is released under the GNU Public License (GPL).

I should have specified, as RedGrittyBrick has said, Dual Monitor KVMs exist.

If the price is a bit much for you (there are some budget ones, but, they can be pricey) Also consider getting 2x normal KVMs and use one just for the screens (Make sure they are powered, or at least the second one is, as some key power from the keyboard/USB port)... I think you just had a bad experience, I have even seen some cheap ones (<£10) from eBay being very good.

Comment: The only issue with Synergy is that one monitor is dedicated to one computer.

Answer (score 4):

You could purchase a dual-monitor KVM switch

> The ███████ 2-port Dual Monitor KVM Switch (DVI+VGA) offers a complete multimedia switching solution, letting users control two Dual Display computers using a single USB mouse and keyboard peripheral set.

or

> This compact 2-port dual monitor KVM switch (DVI+DVI) offers the ultimate in convenience and cost-savings. The dual DVI KVM switch lets you instantly switch back and forth between PCs at the touch of a button, while maintaining professional-quality video on both monitors

or
 ...

Comment: hello, for some reason I can not read the second word of your post, it is blacked out, I don't know who is censoring it but could you please just reply to my comment with missing part? All I can see is "The ####### 2-port Dual ...." where ####### is a black blok.

Comment: It is self-censored, I don't want to advertise or promote a specific untried product just because it came at the top of a list of search results. [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=dual-monitor+KVM)

Answer (score 0):

You could just be connected to one and [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) into other one, that is the real software solution already built into the Windows by default.

If none of the machines has [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) due to being Home Premium or similar editions, then use Team View. It is free for personal use.

Comment: You're making the assumption that at least one of the machines is Win7 Pro or Ultimate.  Home Premium doesn't include an RDP server.

Comment: @MBraedley : Then consider using "Team View", it if free to use specially for personal use like yours.